# how can i insert records of the option that was selected from database?

Tags: php, mysqli

so as you all can see this is a little piece of the form that is causing a problem.

i am getting all the records in the form with a dropdown and want to send the selected result to the database.
after submitting records are inserted correct except this two: $locatie =$_POST["locatie"]; and  $vestiging = $_POST["vestiging"]; 
are inserted as NULL.

i would like it to send the records that was selected in the form.
can someone help me?

```
<form name="nieuwTicket" action="nieuwTicketNieuwKlant.php" method="POST">
    <label class="hidden02">locatie:</label>
    <select name="locatie" class="hidden2">
        <option value = "">---Select---</option>
<?php
$ophaall = "SELECT * FROM locatie ";
$resultl = mysqli_query($connectie, $ophaall);
while ($l = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultl)) {
    echo "<option value='{" . $l['locatieId'] . "}'>" . $l['locatieId'] . " " . $l['locOmschrijving'] . "</option>";
}
?>
    </select><br>
    <label class="hidden02">vestiging:</label>
    <select name="vestiging" class="hidden2"> <!-- Disabled, gaan we nog niets mee doen-->
         <option value = "">---Select---</option>
<?php
$ophaalv = "SELECT * FROM vestigingen ";
$resultv = mysqli_query($connectie, $ophaalv);
while ($v = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultv)) {
    echo "<option value='{" . $v['vestigingId'] . "}'>" . $v['vestigingId'] . " " . $v['vesOmschrijving'] . "</option>";
}
?> 
    </select><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit1" value="invoeren" class="hidden" />
</form>

<!--submit insert to database-->          
<?php          
$locatie = $_POST["locatie"];
$vestiging = $_POST["vestiging"];   

if (isset($_POST['submit1'])) {
// nieuwe klant 
    $insertklant = $connectie->prepare("INSERT INTO klant (klantId, klantAchternaam, klantNaam, klantTel,
    klantAdres, klantPostc, klantStad, klantEmail, instantieId, locatieId)
    VALUES ('',?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
    if ($insertklant) {
        $insertklant->bind_param('sssssssii', $achternaam, $naam, $tel, $adres, $postcode, $stad, $email, $locatie, $vestiging);
        if ($insertklant->execute()) {
            echo ' klant gemaakt!';
        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: What's the purpose of using `{}` in a value attribute?

Comment: You dont do any checking to see if the form has been submitted. Look in your error log, there will be lots to see

Comment: I bet it would also be useful to display the error message `if ($insertklant) {......}else{echo $connectie->error; exit}`

Comment: @u_mulder thank you, it works now.  I forgot about {}.